# Is there a way to automatically change the size of a tkiner window to fit widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I am designing a simple Tkinter GUI program that prints out a table according to a SQL query. However, since I'm not sure how big the query will be, I was wondering if there's a way for the tkinter window to automatically change size to fit the contents? I will be displaying the data just using labels.

Comment: Read [Adding a scrollbar to a group of widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3092341/7414759)

Answer (score 0):

well, i'm not sure what you mean but you can try this code:

`from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry('800x600')

def test():
    window.geometry('600x400')

button = Button(text='test', command=test, font=('times new roman', 30))
button.pack(pady=15)

mainloop()`

if you want the window to automatically to resize you can use if statements
but i would need to see some code to know what you're trying to do!